# Convergence in $L_2$ implies convergence in $L_1$.

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces

I have some doubts if this problem is right. Show that if $X,Y,X_n$ are r.v. in $L_2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ such that $X_n \xrightarrow{L_2} X$, then

$$X_nY \xrightarrow{L_1} XY$$

First of all, I need to prove that $E|X_nY-XY| \to 0$. Then,

$$E|X_nY-XY|=E|(Y)(X_n-X)| \leq \sqrt{E|Y|^2 E|X_n-X|^2},$$

since $X,Y,X_n$ r.v. in $L_2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and Schwarz inequality. But $X_n \xrightarrow{L_2} X$ and hence my proof is done. Is it correct? I think it is too easy. If is not correct any help?

Comment: Your splitting is not generally true. Instead, $\| X_n Y - XY \|_{L^1} \leq \| X_n-X \|_{L^2} \| Y \|_{L^2}$ is Cauchy-Schwarz, and now $\| Y \|_{L^2}$ is just a fixed finite number.

Comment: Looks good to me, except that your equality in the question should be $\leq$.

Comment: My bad, it was a typo. Thanks!